# List of URLs of images in Model, want to draw images in the View

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, binding, wpf-controls

In my Model, I have a list of ImageUrls (as a List), which are all images found from Flickr. I'm looking for a way to draw those images in a WPF Gui and have no idea as how to design the XAML and bind it to this List. Concrete questions:

1. What kind of UIElement can I use?
2. How can I create this UIElement on the fly if the list for example is empty first, and then grows to 5 URLs? Can I for example create a StackPanel and create a UI-Image instance in this per URL?
   or 3. is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For displaying the image, you could just bind an `Image`'s source to the given image URI, using [the `Source` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx).

For dynamically creating images as you add them to your list, I recommend binding to the list of URIs and then creating an item template in your xaml which displays the image; something like this:

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding YourListWithURIs}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}">

<ItemsControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
        <Image Source="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Resources>

</ItemsControl>
```

Given that you bind to a `DataContext` containing a property (list), `YourListWithURIs`. Also, make sure this list is an `ObservableCollection` in order to automatically notify the View when you add or remove items to the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just found the same thing in this 4-part tutorial here: http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2007/08/13/WFP-Tutorial---A-Cool-Image-Viewer.aspx